# Why is $ e^{x/2} \leq 1+x$ for $0 \leq x \leq 2$, and $ e^{x} \geq 1+x$ for all $x$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, power-series, exponential-function

**Question:** Is there a short proof or justification for the following inequality?

$$ e^{x/2} \leq 1+x$$

for $0 \leq x \leq 2$.

I can see this is true by visualising the two functions $e^{x/2}$ and $1+x$ but this is not proof.

---

**Related question:** The following is a similar inequality.

$$ e^{x} \geq 1+x$$

For $x>0$ it is easy to see that the RHS is a subset of the LHS when it is expanded as a power series. What is the strategy for $x<0$?

Comment: You can use the fact that the exponential function is convex. The first inequality then follows because it is true at $x=0$ and at $x=2$. The second inequality is then true since the RHS is the equation for the tangent line to the graph of $e^x$ at $x=0$.

Comment: A silly proof for the second question, using power series: If $x \le -1$, then $1 + x \le 0 < e^x$. If $x \in (-1, 0)$, then inequality is equivalent to $e^{-x} \le \frac{1}{1 - (-x)}$, which is true by comparison of power series (note that $\frac{1}{n!} < 1$ for $n \ge 2$).

Comment: For the second part, calculate the derivative of $f(x) = e^x - (1 + x)$ and conclude that $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing for $x < 0$ and is strictly increasing for $x > 0$ and hence has a minimum at $x = 0$, where $f(x) = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove your second statement: [First Derivative Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_test#First-derivative_test) tells us where a function is increasing or decreasing.  Consider the function $f(x) = e^x - (1 + x)$. We have $f'(x) = e^x - 1$, so $f'(x) < 0$ for $x < 0$ and $f'(x) > 0$ for $x > 0$, which implies $(0, 0)$ is the global minimum of this function on $\Bbb{R}$.

The same argument can be adapted to show that $e^{x/2} \leq 1 + x$ for $x \in [0, a],$ where the particular value of $a > 2$ can be found using the [Lambert W-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).